# After modal window, parent no longer resizable

Tags: java, javafx

I have a root stage which is resizable.

At some point a button click opens a new stage:

```
Stage originalStage = ...
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(originalStage);
```

However when I hide() or close() the new modal stage, the *originalStage* becomes unresizable. At the time of test it is maximized and before/while the modal window is open I see a minimize/maximize/close button.

After the modal window closes I the maximize button **disappears** and I can also no longer resize it (which I could before).

I'm running the oracle JDK 1.8.0_65 on linux.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you think it's a bug, then please file an issue here: http://bugs.java.com/

Answer (score 0):

This thing happens (on Linux only, not Windows, not Mac OS) when modal stage show() is invoked before the parent stage comletely draws itself (i.e. in the constructor).
My workaround is quite simple:

```
Platform.runLater(()-> yourModalStage.show());
```